# Cleanup TFS tbl_TestCodeSignature

Tags: tfs, resource-cleanup

I have a large table in my TFS collection called "tbl_TestCodeSignature" and I want to clean this up, any idea's how?

It looks like this: [image]

I also ran the following query found [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/nipun-jain/2012/10/27/cleanup-redundant-test-impact-data/)

```
select tbc.BuildUri, COUNT(*) from tbl_TestCodeSignature tc
join tbl_TestRun tr on tc.TestRunId = tr.TestRunId
join tbl_buildconfiguration tbc on tbc.BuildConfigurationId = tr.BuildConfigurationId
group by tbc.BuildUri
```

Result:[image]

Answer (score 0):

That data is from builds that have created test impact analysis information.

> The test impact data is mostly stored in tbl_testcodesignature table
>   in project collection database. This table essentially keeps the
>   mapping between a testresult and the impacted CodeSignatures from the
>   product dll. Normally a testcase will use lot of codesingnatures from
>   product so the size of this table grows up in million of rows. Test
>   impact data is associated with a test run which in turn is associated
>   with a particular build. So when a build gets deleted, all the runs
>   associated with a build also gets deleted. As part of run deletion ,
>   we delete test impact data from tbl_testCodeSignature table also. **So
>   one approach to keep check on size of test impact data table is to
>   delete redundant builds which have lot of test impact data.**

Ref: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/nipun-jain/2012/10/27/cleanup-redundant-test-impact-data/